Meaning of letters in VSCode Pull Request Extension messages
I am a (happy!) user of the VSCode Pull Request extension, but unfortunately I was unable to find a complete explanation of the meaning of the letters in the left-pane: when I am reviewing a PR, along files there is sometimes a small cloud (which I ended up understanding as "there has been a discussion about this file") and sometimes this comes with a letter: sometimes a R, or an A, or an M (others, perhaps?). What do they mean?

I don't know of any references or documents specifically about this but typically on Github R stands for Review, A stands for Approved and M stands for Merge.
